# How to focus to a particular cell in a grid after entering value in textBox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to move to  particular cell in a grid, after entering the cell number in textBox.
When I type any number inside the textBox it should auto-focus and scroll to that cell in the grid.

Example - type 601 inside the textBox and it should auto scroll down to that cell

I have attached the sandbox code below
https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-shadow-o9s8w4?file=/demo.tsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your if block with this, it can be done with one extra line!

```js
if (e.target.value) {
  gridItems[e.target.value - 1].style.backgroundColor = "orange";
  gridItems[e.target.value - 1].scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
}
```

**Edit**: [CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-yonath-985vz4)

---

One thing as an extra that I would say is that this is a little inefficient:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 1023; i++) {
  const element = gridItems[i];
  element.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

Consider setting the value of the textbox in a useState hook and passing this as a prop into the Item component and then comparing the Item's index and then deciding whether or not it should be coloured orange.

Comment: Your suggestion doesn't work

Comment: Can you make change in the sandbox code, save it and send your sandbox link over ?

Comment: Added link to post

Comment: Why doesnt it work with handleChange directly ? I tried it

Comment: You need to make sure that if you want to type in `500` it won't just go to `5` and then jump to `50` and then `500`, so pressing `enter` gets around this. The only other way is to use a debounce function like that from `lodash` to wait until the user stops typing and then to call the `handleChange` function